# How to print RGB colour to the terminal

Tags: python, terminal, ansi-escape

Can ANSI escape code SGR 38 - Set foreground color with argument 2;r;g;b be used with print function?
Example of use with code 33 is of course

```
OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
```

I would like to use 038 instead to be able to use any RGB color. Is that posible?

I tried

```
GREEN = '\038[2;0;153;0m'
ENDC = '\033[0m'
    
print(f"{GREEN} some text {ENDC}")
```

Expected to change the color of "some text" in green

Comment: is this an f string? f should be outside

Comment: `\033` is the octal character for ‘escape’, as octals are base 8, there is no `\038` character.

Comment: You still need to use `\033` as the *escape* character for 8bit SGR codes.  The 38, control goes inside the escape sequence.  You can refer to the Description > SGR Parameters > Colors > 8bit section of [this wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for further detail.

Comment: Python can emit any bytes you like but what they do depends on the capabilities of the terminal driver or hardware you are communicating with.

Comment: @S3DEV Based on the []wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) above, at **SGR (Select Graphic Rendition) parameters** table, I understand that \033 comes from:
`30–37  Set foreground color`. 
That's where I found the line that I would like to use with:
`38  Set foreground color  Next arguments are 5;n or 2;r;g;b`. 
So I figured that I should replace 33 with 38 adding the extra arguments. From your comment I understand that I need to use both \033 and \038. Is that right? I think I agree with @tripleee

Comment: @LupascuGabrielCristian - I've just popped a proper answer on to help clarify any misunderstandings and to provide a working code example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use an RGB color space within the terminal* the following escape sequence can be used:

```
# Print Hello! in lime green text.
print('\033[38;2;146;255;12mHello!\033[0m')
#           ^
#           |
#           \ The 38 goes here, to indicate a foreground colour.

# Print Hello! in white text on a fuschia background.
print('\033[48;2;246;45;112mHello!\033[0m')
```

Explanation:

```
\033[38;2;146;255;12mHello!\033[0m
^     ^ ^  ^   ^   ^   ^     ^   ^ 
|     | |  R   G   B   |     |   |
|     | |  |           |     |   \ Reset the colour to default
|     | |  |           |     | 
|     | |  |           |     \ Escape character
|     | |  |           |
|     | |  \ R;G;B     \ Text to print
|     | |
|     | \ Indicate the following sequence is RGB
|     |
|     \ Code to instruct the setting of an 8 or 24-bit foreground (text) colour
|
\ Escape character
```

The use of `38;2` indicates an RGB (foreground) sequence is to follow. However, the use of `38;5` indicates the following (foreground) value comes from the [256-colour table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#8-bit).

To clarify what appears to be a misconception, `\033` (octal) or `\x1b` (hexidecimal) corresponds to the ASCII table's [ESC character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), which is used here to introduce an escape sequence of terminal text colouring.  Whereas the `38` is used to instruct the following 8 or 24-bit colour to be set as *foreground*, (*after* the escape sequence has been introduced). Additionally, `48` can be used to set the *background* colour, as demonstrated in the code example above.

*Providing the terminal emulator supports 24-bit colour sequences. (e.g. Xterm, GNOME terminal, etc.)

Link to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#24-bit) which explains this topic of 24-colour (RGB) in greater depth.

Answer (score 4):

In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) package. [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) is lightweight, less verbose and supports RGB colors out of the box. Simply install the package with `pip install colorist` and type:

```py
from colorist import ColorRGB, BgColorRGB

dusty_pink = ColorRGB(194, 145, 164)
bg_steel_blue = BgColorRGB(70, 130, 180)

print(f"I want to use {dusty_pink}dusty pink{dusty_pink.OFF} and {bg_steel_blue}steel blue{bg_steel_blue.OFF} colors inside this paragraph")
```

[image: Examples of RGB color in terminal]

If you prefer to define colors in HSL, that's also possible as [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) will translate this to RGB:

```py
from colorist import ColorHSL, BgColorHSL

mustard_green = ColorHSL(60, 56, 43)
bg_steel_gray = BgColorHSL(190, 2, 49)

print(f"I want to use {mustard_green}mustard green{mustard_green.OFF} and {bg_steel_gray}steel blue{bg_steel_gray.OFF} colors inside this paragraph")
```

[image: Examples of HSL color in terminal]

Or similarly, you can also define colors in Hex:

```py
from colorist import ColorHex, BgColorHex

watermelon_red = ColorHex("#ff5733")
bg_mint_green = BgColorHex("#99ff99")

print(f"I want to use {watermelon_red}watermelon pink{watermelon_red.OFF} and {bg_mint_green}mint green{bg_mint_green.OFF} colors inside this paragraph")
```

[image: Examples of Hex color in terminal]

Note that not all terminals support advanced RGB colors as they weren't part of the initial [ANSI specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). You may want to try various terminals to find the right one for you.

Answer (score -3):

Below code will give you an idea.

```py
print('\033[90m' + 'hello' + '\033[96m' + ' there?' )
```

Comment: OP’s question is regarding the use of 24bit ( RGB) colours.  1) This demonstrates 3 and 4 bit colours, as already shown by OP’s question.  2) Remember to *reset* the colour at the end of the sequence, otherwise any text to follow will be of the same colour.

Comment: yes you are right.